# Incompleteness in other areas of mathematics

Tags: logic

I read in "Apostolos Doxiadis:Uncle Petros and Goldbach's conjecture" that **SPOILER ALERT** Uncle Petros practically stopped working on Goldbach's Conjecture when he learnt about the Incompleteness Theorem. He asked Godel if it could be decided if a particular statement is true but unprovable and Godel said he couldn't tell if even Goldbach's Conjecture is such.
But as I understand Godel's theorem, this incompleteness only applies to a realtively small number of statements which somehow refer back to themselves.

So isn't it very probable that Number Theory problems (like Goldbach's Conjecture), or conjectures from areas of mathematics not closely related to formal logic, don't belong to the group of true but unprovable statements?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  Please refer to [ask] for some guidelines on how to participate in helping to build a site with curated and supportable mathematical content.  The Community is not a chat-style forum, as you may have expected, but if your Question can be narrowed to a problem with a mathematically supportable Answer, we may be able to help.

Comment: If you had a useful decision process for which statements were true but unprovable, you'd be able to prove that they were true.

Comment: Anyway Oncle Petro is a literary character quite sympathetic. Read the novel.

Comment: @MarkBennet Certain classes of statements which basically everyone agrees as true are unprovable in formal logic.  Many of them aren't hard to spot once you fully understand the formation rules for well-formed formulas and terms.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood Fair enough, but for the record I intended "a useful decision process" to indicate more formality than "basically everyone agrees"

Comment: The true but unprovable statements are not always artificial. Undecidability even appears in diophantine equations (as mentioned below). And Goldbach's conjecture could well be true, but unprovable! Also Collatz conjecture or Riemann hypothesis. As long as a problem is unsolved, in general there is no way to find out whether a proof is impossible or just extremely hard. There are of course exceptions, like the continuum hypothesis.

Comment: Remark to the above book : The mentioned professor never lived.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When contemplating provability, it is useful to remember that it pertains to a particular framework (usualy, a formal system). Also, truth should be argued somehow, so one also wants to rely on a framework when demonstrating the truth of a statement.

I have not read the book, so I would not know what proof means Uncle Petros treated himself to when trying to prove Goldbach's conjecture.

To provide counterexamples to the hypothesized link between incompleteness and self-reference, I want to point out "natural" (in the sense of being of considerable interest independently of the incompleteness theorem) statements that are unprovable in Peano arithmetic, but true in its standard model, as seen through the lens of Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory. Admittedly, Peano arithmetic is probably not the natural habitat of a working mathematician; still, it is a prominent first-order theory of natural numbers.

Both statements are combinatorial. One is an apparently slight strengthening of the [finite Ramsey theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem), conditioning additionally that a certain monochromatic set, whose existence is stipulated by the theorem, should be at least of the cardinality of its least element. A well-known result of [Paris and Harrington](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris%E2%80%93Harrington_theorem) says that this stronger statement is unprovable in PA. One can argue its truth by appealing to a stronger theory, such as ZF or second-order arithmetic.

The other example pertains to [Goodstein sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodstein%27s_theorem#Goodstein_sequences); Goodstein's theorem tells us that each such sequence eventually reaches zero; Kirby and Paris proved that this result is not a theorem of PA.

As to *probability* of (un)provability, that is presumably quite difficult to assess. Provability in a theory has nothing to do with whether or not the statement is "self-referential". Naturally, some of the statements that have resisted either proving or disproving for a long time may raise the question of the adequacy of the formal means employed in the attempts.

Answer (score 4):

What about questions asking whether some big, multi-variable polynomial equation (with integer coefficients) has an integer solution? There are equations of this sort for which there is no integer solution but the usual Zermelo-Fraenkel axioms of set theory can't prove that.  (If you add to ZFC the assumption that there is an inaccessible cardinal, then the unsolvability of some such equations becomes provable, but for other such equations you need bigger large-cardinal axioms.)

Comment: And if there are such equations then how can one be sure that they really have no solutions (if it is impossible to prove with the given axioms)?

Comment: @MatthewPanks For some of these equations, I'm sure they have no solutions because I'm sure inaccessible cardinals exist. The same goes for somewhat larger cardinals.  For much larger cardinals, like measurable ones, I'm not confident that they actually exist, but I'm confident that there are inner models in which they exist; that's enough to imply that the corresponding equations have no solutions.  Even larger cardinals leave me unsure